# Oracle Apex Date Picker shows as text item

Tags: oracle-apex-5

Date picker displays as normal text item in Apex 5.0. I double checked the property under Identification and it is set to "Date Picker"

I'm using the normal wizard to create date picker. My theme is universal 42, standard template, nothing special

Has anyone come across this as a bug? I don't feel I'm missing anything

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you set read only properties date picker displays date as bold text